# How to connect bass to windows box and record the session?

Tags: bass-guitar, recording

Basically I would like to connect my bass to my PC running Windows.
I have read about two forms:

1. Connect my bass to my pc using the MIC jack in the box or and USB cable but I can get a problem about some little latency.
2. Use and USB AUDIO INTERFACE (it's the best option an is recommended).

The problem with the second point is, there are so much information. I found two product (I think there are more):

a) avid - this is quite expensive because it includes software pro-tools (that only work with avid product),

b) tascam (usb-100) is quite cheaper, but the problem is it does not provide software.

Are there other *usb audio interface* or *software* I can buy?

Basically what I would like to do is:

```
a. play the base track and listen.
b. record my session while I listen the base track and my session.
c. record a video.
d. mix it all together.
```

Comment: See my answer to this: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7569/recording-electric-guitar-with-pc-suggestions-to-get-a-great-metal-sound?rq=1 -- the principles are the same on a bass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for product recommendations, it gets a bit tricky, as there are many, and it depends on your specific requirements (functionality, cost etc) but to answer your question:

Don't use the mic input - it is not designed for this and you will get noise

Ideally, use an external soundcard. If your PC has a very good internal soundcard, that may be okay, but there is really no substitute for an external card, with proper inputs. Mine is an M-Audio with 16 separate inputs (ranging from balanced Mics, line-in, 3/4" jack sockets etc)

If you want to be able to play along with a track, you will need multitrack software. There is a huge range of tools here - I use Sonar and Cubase (relatively cheap but extremely powerful), but you need to look at matching your requirements with the various products.

You don't need an external recording device - you can do all of this in software.

For recording video, you could use free tools such as Windows Movie Maker, or you could go for commercial software. There are various questions on avp.stackexchange.com that cover this off.