# Home studio for guitar question

Tags: guitar, recording

I just purchased a focusrite solo 2gen and still can't make a nice recording.  The interface is working but the sound is not terrible as I only use the provided Ableton Live, which means no effects and no amp simulation.

I also have a digitech rp255 pedal and a blackstar ht1r.  But I still didn't figure out how to get the best sound out of all this. Do I need some additional softwares? What do I need if I wanna plug and play (recording with an amp simulation software) ?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Are you recording via a microphone into the Focusrite or are you connecting your instrument directly to it? What's the specific problem you have with the sound - is it poor quality or just not like a commercial recording?

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at [this post](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23896/how-to-record-my-guitar-on-my-computer?rq=1) and see if it has any tips you might use.

Comment: I plug the guitar directly. The sound is poor. I might purchase a mic later but for now i'd like to record direct

Comment: For electric guitar you'll almost certainly want to reamp -- take a look at the [LePou](http://lepouplugins.blogspot.com/) amp sims. They're free, and very good.

Comment: Or for something a little more "all in one," check out the free versions of [Guitar Rig](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/guitar/guitar-rig-5-player/) and [Amplitude](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/amplitubecs/).

Answer (score 1):

I've recorded my guitar at home using a Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 and Ableton Live with decent results.

I plugged my guitar directly into the input, making sure I've selected the 'Instrument' setting.

Be careful with the gain - don't let it go into the red on your recording.

I don't know exactly what you mean by

> the sound is poor

When I record the sound is just what comes out of the instrument - if you want to use an amp plugin there are many [free ones available](http://blog.reddogmusic.co.uk/2012/12/15/6-free-vst-guitar-plugins-thatll-blow-yourmind/) but not knowing what the specific problem is makes it hard to give any specific answers.